Drill batteries
My old 12 V B&D original drill battery (NiMH) has died.
I thought about replacing the 10 cells (if I can get them in the UK). Whatever I do, I want to be better than the original gear.

Do I have to stick to NiMH ?
Can I consider lithium ?
I was concerned about the heat from soldering, but is it okay?
Do I have to stick to 12 V? I read that some people have used 14 V batteries - can this work?


Both my father and I both had 18 V NiMH drills, both hammered our battery packs. I rebuilt my battery pack with 5S LiPo, nominal 18 V but max 21 V. The drill has worked fine. I whacked the battery pack into my Dad's drill and boom, the electronics let the smoke out. Just because somebody else's over voltage gamble paid off doesn't mean yours will.

You can try all of the above options, 12V, 14V, high discharge (>50A) Li-Ion, whatever. And you will need a charger for the Li-Ion. It will cost you money and time. But the best option is to trash the cheap B&D drill and buy something modern, it will be much more effective use of your funds.

Barry, very well thought out points to ask about on your overall question about "replacing with better." So +1 for that reason.

If you have a 12V NiMH battery pack, it is meant to be used in that ecosystem, meaning, the pack monitor IC expects to see 10 NiMH cells, the drill expects voltage range of 10 NiMH cells, and charger expects to charge 10 NiMH cells.
So for the questions:

Yes you have to stick to 10 NiMH cells, as none of your items connected to the cells are compatible with anything else. Unless you want to redesign everything, and then it makes sense to just buy a new drill with pack and charger.

Yes you can always consider Lithium, but after reading the #1, the result after consideration should be no, you don't want to change to Lithium

It depends. Some cells can handle soldering them together. The packs are often welded together though, which may be a safer option if heat is a concern.

Yes you should stick to 12V, as no part of the system does not expect anything else than 12V pack of 10 NiMH cells. There is no way you can attach a different amount of cells to a BMS made for 10 cells.



I tried. It's not worth the hassle.

It is pretty hard to get better than the original gear:


NiMH cells are not mass-produced anymore. Li-Ion took most of the market. If you buy today NiMH cells, they will be of lower quality, lower performance or quite expensive.
Even ~10 years ago it was hard to find high-current NiMHs. I ended up filling the old battery pack with Eneloop cells and while it worked, the instrument lost a lot of torque.


Li-Ion is good... as long as you can fit them in the voltage range. 3 in series Li-Ion (3.6 /3.7V per cell) with some tweaking in the charger, or 4 in series LiFePO4 (3.2V per cell, okay-ish wit the original charger) will probably work, provided you can fit them in the old box together with the battery management board of proper parameters.

In regard to soldering - don't, esp. with Li-Ion. Point welding is the known safe method. It is neither hard nor expensive.

Higher voltage may get you some more performance, but may as well kill the motor controller. What is more important is that you will need to tweak the charger a lot, in order to charge the higher voltage pack.


